# react hooks How to render data groupby

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am having an issue with groupby the data and render.

data look like below

```
{
    "movies": [
        {
            "picture": "https:url/fajeiowfjaoeif23134.jpg",
            "genres": [
                "Action",
                "Crime",
                "Drama"
            ]
        },
        {
            "picture": "https:url/237192837ahfhauwiefuh.jpg",
            "genres": [
                "Animation",
                "Adventure",
                "Family"
            ]
        },   
        {
            "picture": "https://url/372702a0-3e49-4bf3-812a-0c241a8c5ac9.jpg",
            "genres": [
                "Crime",
                "Drama"
            ]
        },
        {
            "picture": "https:url/d8cbdc3d-c683-4a59-aae3-9a7327f0743a.jpg",
            "genres": [
                "Crime",
                "Drama",
                "Thriller"
            ]
        },
        {
            "picture": "https://url/529c7379-ccfe-4003-a2ba-6c0a2ffd6704.jpg",
            "genres": [
                "Biography",
                "Drama",
                "History"
            ]
         }
```

What I'm trying is to group by Genre and render picture in each genre so that it looks like below.

```
Genre A
Picture Picture Picture Picture

Genre B
Picture Picture Picture Picture

and so on
```

I was able to render by Genre but having hard time how to render pictures under the genres. If movies genres array contains `Action, Crime, Drama` then the picture has to be rendered in Action, Crime, and Dram genres. Below is my code.

```
function Genre() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [genre, setGenre] = useState([]);

  const getMovies = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('url', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer *********',
        },
      });
      const parseRes = await response.json();
      const fetchedData = parseRes.movies;

      setMovies(fetchedData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getMovies();
  }, []);

  const getGenre = () => {
    let genreArray = [];
    movies.map((movie) => {
      let theGenre = movie.genres;
      for (let i = 0; i < theGenre.length; i++) {
        if (genreArray.includes(theGenre[i]) === false) {
          genreArray.push(theGenre[i]);
        }
      }
    });
    setGenre(genreArray);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getGenre();
  }, [movies]);

  const renderGenre = () => {
    return genre.map((data, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <p>Genre {data}</p>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  return <React.Fragment>{renderGenre()}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a separate function to get all the pictures by genre name. Something like:

```
const getPicturesByGenre = (genre) => {
  let pictures = [];
  movies.map((movie) => { 
    const hasGenre = movie.genres.includes(genre);
    if (hasGenre) pictures.push(movie.picture);
  })
  return pictures;
}
```

and then loop over this new array and render the image for each genre:

```
  const renderPicturesByGenre = () => {
    return genre.map((genre) => (
      return getPicturesByGenre(genre).map((pics) => (<img src="pics" />))
    ));
  };
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/henrylee0327/05228590324bdcb587eef6398f6f0fa1

Comment: Could you show me the error? I can't replicate it unless I spin up an entire react app

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vudiylp5rjfm5l0/Screen%20Shot%202021-04-18%20at%2011.12.05%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: add a `key` attribute to the img tag and give it a unique value. Something like `<img src="pics" key="pics" />`

Comment: Ok. So I added an index key and it is solved. But it is not rendering a picture. pictures are coming from url which just like this "https://wookie.codesubmit.io/static/posters/84b17b50-5c6b-4c00-a798-f83ddda0187d.jpg"

Comment: I changed it to <img src={pics} key={index}/> and it is working! Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Nice! Just a heads up, using the index for the key is sometimes not recommended if you need to maintain order. So try making it something you know will be unique every time. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
function Genre() {
    const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
    const [genre, setGenre] = useState([]);

    const getMovies = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('url', {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'Bearer *********',
                },
            });
            const parseRes = await response.json();
            const fetchedData = parseRes.movies;

            setMovies(fetchedData.movies);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getMovies();
    }, []);

    
    const getGenre = () => {
        const groupedByGenre = movies.reduce((accu, { genres = [], picture = '' }) => {
            genres.forEach((genre) => {
                accu[genre] = accu[genre] ? [...accu[genre], picture] : [picture]
            })
            return accu
        }, {})
        setGenre(groupedByGenre);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getGenre();
    }, [movies, getGenre]);

    const renderGenre = () => {
        return Object.entries.reduce((acc, item) => {
            const [genreName, pictures] = item
            const genersList = pictures.map((picture) => {
                return (
                    <div key={picture}>
                        <p>{genreName} {picture}</p>
                    </div>
                )
            })
            acc.push(...genersList)
            return acc
        }, [])
    };

    return <React.Fragment>{renderGenre()}</React.Fragment>;
}
```

Comment: I'm getting "TypeError: Object.entries.reduce is not a function" I will just share all my code with access to the API. Can you please check below?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/henrylee0327/a419d8675b22f9d69c57da7b4d22bfd9